# angular2 rx javascript, unable to handle html response with a proper response object

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm sending a request like so,

```ts
return this.http.post(this.summaryDevicesV2, body, options)
    .retry(1)
    .map((res: Response) => this.winRef.baseSuccessHandler(res) )
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(this.winRef.baseErrorHandler(error)));
```

for the most part, it handles everything fine, both success and errors, untill i get an html response, then i get this error.

```ts
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0,
```

instead of a proper response object.  There might be situations where I get none json for different error scenarios/reasons, I would like to treat these scenarios differently, and am unable to due to the fact I can't access the headers and status code due to getting a string, instead of a proper response object.  Is there any way of getting access to these properties?

EDIT

Her's something I've tried in the base error handler to deal with this situation.  It's always happening in the error scenario because the server is actually throwing a 302 redirect with some html in it's body.  I'd like to catch the error code, but I'm unable to access anything from the error object, the status and headers are undefined in this situation.  And if I print out the error I'll just see a stacktrace.  I understand that it's not proper json, but I would think it'd only try to parse the json when I call error.json();

```ts
try {
   console.log("error type", typeof error);
   console.log("keys", Object.keys(error) );
   let smError = "SyntaxError";
   let smError2 = "Unexpected token < in JSON";
   error += "";
   if(error.indexOf(smError) != -1 && error.indexOf(smError2) != -1){
      location.reload();
   }
   console.log("sm error?", error);
} catch(e) {
   ;
}
```

This is just one of the thing's i've tried, because I can't seem to access the headers or status code.

The first log says it's type object
But the object has no properties.

And in a different scneairo, where the server responds with a 400, the keys that are returned are like so.

```ts
"_body"
1
:
"status"
2
:
"ok"
3
:
"statusText"
4
:
"headers"
5
:
"type"
6
:
"url"
```

Current Solution:

Currently I'm just checking how many properties are in the response error object, and if is below 1, I assume I got back the html redirect.

Comment: Add source of this function `this.winRef.baseSuccessHandler(res)`

Comment: Your code seema fine you are probably doing something in above mentioned method try to add source of this method

Comment: Your question will be downvoted if isn't updated why you ppl ask and move away :/

Comment: The error is because you're trying to parse JSON, but it's failing, because it looks like your request is returning HTML (hence the unexpected token `<`). We'll need to see the source of `baseSuccessHandler` and `baseErrorHandler` to actually be able to debug the problem though.

Comment: The json conversion is an issue, but it's not  an issue I'm causing, the object I'm receiving from the observable is unusable.